# About the order of variable declaration in PHP

Tags: php

I've tried the following code in php :

```
<?php
$year=1900;
$month=1;
$tmp = date_create_from_format("Y-n-d",$year."-".$month."-01");
$start_datetimeobject = $tmp;
$end_datetimeobject = date_add($tmp, date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 month"));
$end_datetimeobject = date_sub($end_datetimeobject,date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 day"));
$end_date = date_format($end_datetimeobject,"Y-m-d");
$start_date = date_format($start_datetimeobject,"Y-m-d");
echo "Start = ",$start_date;
echo nl2br("\n");
echo "End = ",$end_date;
?>
```

and got the following result :

```
Start = 1900-01-31
End = 1900-01-31
```

... which I find surprising.
Now if I modify my code to define the `$start_date variable` immediately after having assigned the datetime object :

```
<?php
$year=1900;
$month=1;
$tmp = date_create_from_format("Y-n-d",$year."-".$month."-01");
$start_datetimeobject = $tmp;
$start_date = date_format($start_datetimeobject,"Y-m-d");
$end_datetimeobject = date_add($tmp, date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 month"));
$end_datetimeobject = date_sub($end_datetimeobject,date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 day"));
$end_date = date_format($end_datetimeobject,"Y-m-d");
echo "Start = ",$start_date;
echo nl2br("\n");
echo "End = ",$end_date;
?>
```

...  it works as I expected :

```
Start = 1900-01-01
End = 1900-01-31
```

Can someone explain me why ? I am not very familiar with PHP but have practiced Perl in the past, and I don't understand what happens ...

Comment: Cloning the DateTime object is also possible: $start_datetimeobject = clone $tmp;

Answer (score 0):

This is due to [`date_add`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) altering its received date in place. I'd highly recommend using [`DatetimeImmutable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) instead whenever possible to avoid such situations. It will ensure (as the class name indicates) that your dates can never be altered (methods will return altered copies instead).

Let's take the relevant lines of your first sample, one by one:

```
$tmp = date_create_from_format("Y-n-d",$year."-".$month."-01");
```

This creates a `DateTime` object and binds the `$tmp` variable to it.

```
$start_datetimeobject = $tmp;
```

This makes `$start_datetimeobject` reference the same object as `$tmp` (so, that same date), since objects are copied ["by reference"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) in PHP.

```
$end_datetimeobject = date_add($tmp, date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 month"));
```

This adds 1 month to the date referenced by `$tmp`, modifying it. Since `$start_datetimeobject` references the same object, it will now reference the +1 month date as well.

Therefore, when you do this a few lines further:

```
$start_date = date_format($start_datetimeobject,"Y-m-d");
```

The start date is based on an unwanted `$start_datetimeobject` date.

This doesn't happen in your second sample because by doing that last line first,
it happens before `$start_datetimeobject` gets modified.

Comment: Thanks, very clear.
I suspected something like that and tried a very simple example such as :
`$var=3;`
`$var2=$var;`
`$var=$var+1;`
`echo $var2;`
but did not reproduce the same thing. I still have some work to do, it seems :)